# Changing the styles dynamically in Angular

Tags: .net, angular, redis

I have a frontend in Angular and backend in dotnet 6.
The user should be able to change the color theme of the website.
The problem is that all the styles are collected and compressed during the build process. That means I should somewhere store my styles and apply it. which can take some time.
I have now 2 option to solve this problem. I need your help to tell me which way is the better way and why, and if there is another option, I would appreciate it :D

Solution one: I craete a json file in my asset folder in my Angular project, and read the styles from there. if somebody change the style, I would change the json. This method is very fast, because the data are not stored in database and there is no extra call to backend to retrieve data.

Solution two: I store this data in Redis Cache. In this case the frontend call the backedn but the data are in cache and in fraction of second it can respond.

So now I need your opinions.
Many tnx in advance.

Answer (score 1):

I don't understand. Can't you have one shared variabilized style (with css variables) and one class for each theme, in :root of the root style sheet, which defines variable values?

Then for the next time, you can cache the user choice (only the theme name) in the browser or link it to the user in the backend. But it's up to you to choose if you want the user to keep his theme across many computers, or not.

Comment: Sorry that I'm answering too late. I was sick. I don't know what do you mean with css variables. I want that the admin user can choose from a color palate his/her own colors. That means is is not only couple of colors from which you can choose, but they can have any color. can you pls explain me in more details your solution? tnx in advance